# How to create a trigger to insert new users details to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, user-registration

Im trying to "synchronize" an external forum script (SMF) with my website.
Thats means, when a user registers in my website, a trigger insert the user details (username, password and email) in the external forum members table.
Something like that, but its wrong, sql error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER forumReg 
AFTER INSERT ON hotaru_users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO forum_members (member_name, email_address, passwd)
    VALUES (NEW.user_username, NEW.user_email, NEW.user_password);
END
```

hotaru_users is my website users table,
forum_members is the external forum users table,
both tables are in the same mysql database

the error

```
Erro

consulta SQL:

CREATE TRIGGER forumReg AFTER INSERT ON hotaru_users
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO forum_members( member_name, email_address, passwd )
VALUES (
NEW.user_username, NEW.user_email, NEW.user_password
);

Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

Comment: What's the error?  Is "hotaru_users" and "forum_members" part of the same database, or on different server?

Comment: @Yuck: that wasn't clear yet at the time I posted my comment....

Comment: presumably, the forum members table is in a different DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove the `BEGIN`, `END`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER forumReg 
AFTER INSERT ON hotaru_users 
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO forum_members (member_name, email_address, passwd)
    VALUES (NEW.user_username, NEW.user_email, NEW.user_password);
```

or change the delimiter for the creation of the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER forumReg 
AFTER INSERT ON hotaru_users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO forum_members (member_name, email_address, passwd)
    VALUES (NEW.user_username, NEW.user_email, NEW.user_password);
END 
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: that fixed the sql error and is successfuly inserting the user details in the forum members table, but i figured out that the password is hashed so it is storing the wrong password. Is there a way to handle this hash thing?

Comment: Where is the hashing done? In the application code? With another trigger when the row is inserted in `hotaru_users`?

Comment: When users registers to my website, the password is stored hashed in hotaru_users table, when the trigger above is executed, the hashed password is inserted in forum_members table. So when i try to login forum i get incorrect password.

Comment: Is it hashed again when it is inserted in `forum_members`? So, it is double-hashed?

Comment: no, its exactly equal to the value in hotaru_users, its not double hashed. But i think the kind of hash used in my website and SMF are different, so im getting incorrect password.

Comment: So, I don't get the problem. It's usual to store hashed passwords. Do you want to store it as plain, unhashed password in `forum_members`? Ah, OK, i see the edit now about different hash algorithms.

Comment: yes, the SMF uses this algorithm http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=310140.0 im trying to figure out what algorithm my cms uses.. with that info you think i can handle this hash thing?

Comment: I guess one way in that case would be to make this trigger a `BEFORE INSERT` one, send the plain password to `forum_members` and hash it with that hash algorithm (with trigger or other code).

Comment: @ypercut, tried BEFORE, now the value stored in forum_members table is different from the value in hotaru_members. But i still getting incorrect password.

Comment: This is how my website hash the passwords `public function generateHash($plainText, $salt = null)
 {
  $salt_length = 9;
  if ($salt === null) {
   $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, $salt_length); }
  else {
   $salt = substr($salt, 0, $salt_length);
  }
  return $salt . sha1($salt . $plainText);
 }`

Comment: @LucasMatos: I think you should post another question for that. Add the info of how you calculate password hashes, how SMF does and what you want (both forums to work with same password).

Comment: And try to go over your older questions and accept answers if they were helpful.

Comment: well, i actually made something that is working.. Its not very beauty to see but, i removed the password from trigger, and im inserting the password to forum_members table via sql after the registration process =D its a temporary solution while i figure out how to register via SMF API. Thank you all!!! =*